# Algorithm to desaturate RGB color

Tags: algorithm, colors, rgb, hsv

I have a question. Is there some way or some algorithm that I can use to desaturate an RGB value without converting the color to HSV or HSL? My RGB input is going to be fully saturated, therefore I just need a way to desaturate my color.

I'm working on a color picker and I need a fast and efficient way of doing this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple approach (ignoring perceived lumunance like `0.3R+0.6G+0.11B` and other formulas):

Initial color `(r,g,b)`
Gray color of the same intensity `(i,i,i)`
where `i = (r + g + b) / 3`

Deviations from gray components:

```
dr = i - r
dg = i - g
db = i - b
```

Let parameter `t` changes from 0 for initial saturated color to 1 for gray color. So

```
r' = r + dr * t  
g' = g + dg * t
b' = b + db * t
```

Comment: And negative values give oversaturated colors.

Comment: When going negative, be aware of over- / underflow

Comment: But why would you ignore perceived luminance..

Comment: @arkon Because this is simple approximation. We can recalculate formulas with coefficients, but color tone will change too! More correct way is to use HSV or HSL, but author wanted to avoid this.